# Why do I have a bug displaying a custom popup in a Thread?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Why do I have a bug displaying a custom popup in a Thread?

I'm using a custom popup that appears in the bottom right-hand corner of the screen and disappears a few seconds later.

But when I try to display this personalized popup in a Thread, it bugs, i.e. I have to click on the desktop for the popup to appear, but without the alert icon and without the alert message. My mouse is on hold and the program no longer responds.

I have no problem displaying a message with "MessageBox".

What's strange is that if I use my "personal popup" and "messageBox" at the same time, my popup is displayed correctly but it doesn't disappear after a few seconds and the program no longer responds.

Do you know what the problem is?

Here's the code:

```
                    this.ThreadAutoCheck = new Thread((ThreadStart)(async () =>
                {
                    TelegramBotService telegramBotService = new TelegramBotService(this.txtTelegramKey.Texts.Trim());
                    string chatId = this.txtChannelID.Texts.Trim();
                    while (this.ThreadAutoCheck != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            List<Position> otherPositions = new List<Position>();
                            foreach (string str in lstUID)
                            {
                                string uid = str;
                                List<Position> positions = await apkApi.GetPositions(uid, type);
                                if (positions == null || positions.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    this.Alert("No data to display.", FAlert.enmType.Warning);
                                }
```

I've searched but haven't found any questions that match my problem.

Comment: You have to start a message loop, either showing a Form with `ShowDiailog()` (which calls `Applicarion.RunDialog()`) or using `Application.Run()`, both start a message loop. Use `Thread.SetApartmentState()` to set `ApartmentState.STA` -- This all you have here is not a good idea. You could show a Toast Notification instead

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have absolutely no idea what you mean... Do you have an example?
Precisely in the code I use a Toast Notification

Comment: [Send a local toast notification from a C# app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast). Or, if you need to support Windows 7, use the standard NotifyIcon

Comment: Thanks, I've seen some tutorials but it's about using it... how do I use message loop in my code?

Comment: I've already described this in my first comment -- You should post code that makes sense to whomever is reading it. The fragment you have posted doesn't make clear what you're doing there. More specifically, what is `Alert(...)` doing, what this methods handles and a description of the reason why you think you need a secondary Thread for this

Comment: In Windows Forms, UI components can only be accessed and manipulated from the main UI thread. Unexpected behavior or crashes may result if you try to update UI elements from a different thread. So you need to make sure that any code that updates custom popups or any other UI elements executes on the main UI thread. You can use the Invoke or BeginInvoke methods to marshal calls to the UI thread.